# I need to disable the decrement button when the quantity is 1. How is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, handlebars.js

In the cart,  quantity. I need to disable the decrement button otherwise I get an error and the Product is lost when quantity goes below one. help me please give a solution,

**This is the cart**

> > > cart.hbs

```
<button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number" onclick="changeQuandity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user}}',-1)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</button>

<span class="text-center" name=" quantity" id="{{this.product._id}}">{{this.quantity}}</span>
<button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" onclick="changeQuandity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user}}',1)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
</button>
```

and also  am using ajax in hbs;
here am passing quantity, count and URL,

```
<script>
    function changeQuandity(cartId, proId, userId, count) {
            let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML)
            count = parseInt(count)
            console.log(userId)
    
            $.ajax({
                url: '/change-product-quandity',
                data: {
                    user: userId,
                    cart: cartId,
                    product: proId,
                    count: count,
                    quantity: quantity,
                },
    
                method: 'post',
                success: (response) => {
                    location.reload();
                    {
                        document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = quantity + count
                        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = response.total
                    }
                }
    
            })
        }
    
    </script>
```

here am  using the aggregate method,
and,  the  changeproductQuandity and get getTotalAmount
count and quantity  details are here,

> > userhelper.js

```
 changeproductQuandity:(details)=>{
        details.count=parseInt(details.count);
      details.quantity=parseInt(details.quantity)
     
          return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
              if(details.count==-1 && details.quantity==1){
                db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION)
                .updateOne({_id:objectId(details.cart)}, 
            {
    
                $pull:{products:{item:objectId(details.product)}}
            }
                ).then(response)
            }else{
          db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION)
                .updateOne({_id:objectId(details.cart),'products.item':objectId(details.product)},
                {
                    $inc:{'products.$.quantity':details.count}
                }
                
                ).then((response)=>{ 
    
                    resolve({status:true})
                    
                })   
            }
    
          })
      },
       getTotalAmount:(userId)=>{
            return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
                let total=await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
                    {
                        $match:{user:objectId(userId)}
                    },
                    {
                        $unwind:'$products'
                    },{
                        $project:{
                            item:'$products.item',
                            quantity:'$products.quantity',
                         
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup:{
                            from:collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                            localField:'item',
                            foreignField:'_id',
                            as:'product'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $project:{
                            item:1,quantity:1,product:{$arrayElemAt:['$product',0]}
                        } 
                    },
                    {
                        $group:{ 
                            _id:null, 
                            total:{$sum:{$multiply:[{ $toInt: '$quantity'},{ $toInt: '$product.Price' }]}}
                        }
                    }
         
                ]).toArray()
                resolve(total[0].total)
```

Two types of errors are getting here when the Quantity goes below one the product is removed from the cart, and, also,

resolve(total[0].total)
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

because of this, do I need to disable the decrement button when the quantity is 1? I assuming using this idea the error never gets. please help me.

Comment: I think you should share your `changeQuandity` function as well as what code you have tried to achieve the disabling.

Comment: ok, please helpme

Comment: What is the purpose of the `location.reload();` in the `success` handler of the AJAX request sent in your `changeQuandity` function? If you are reloading the page, I don't think those `document.getElementById()` calls will be doing anything.

Comment: Even after I removed location.reload(); , am   getting an error , Two or three times when I click the  decrement button am getting ,                                          resolve(total[0].total)
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')   how to solce this

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code in your question. Rather than re-write it all, I am just going to provide some suggestions about how I would handle this.

First, while disabling the decrement button *is* a good idea, I don't think it is sufficient for a well-coded application. The server endpoint that handles the setting of the new total should not crash if an invalid `total` is sent. Instead, it should check for an invalid `total` amount and return a [4xx - Client Error HTTP response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses) in a such case.

Once your server has that protection in place, you can go about improving your client-side. I think you should disable the button in two cases:

1. When a new total has been submitted and you are waiting for the server to return the `{ status: true }` response.
2. When the total has its minimum allowed value, ie. `0`.

For your code, this could look like:

```
function changeQuandity(cartId, proId, userId, count) {
  let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML)
  count = parseInt(count)

  // Note: a more specific selector for your quantity change buttons would be preferred
  const quantityChangeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]');

  quantityChangeButtons.forEach(button => button.disabled = true);
    
  $.ajax({
    url: '/change-product-quandity',
    data: {
      user: userId,
      cart: cartId,
      product: proId,
      count: count,
      quantity: quantity,
    }, 
    method: 'post',
    success: (response) => {
      document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = quantity + count
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = response.total
    }),
    complete: () => {
      if (count > 0) {
        quantityChangeButtons.forEach(button => button.disabled = false);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I have provided a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/47dwev2r/) with a simplified example.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you sir. the error is still getting,  am a Self Learner so, nobody else to helping me, the error is coming from usershelpers.js, the error is **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')** .   **the error comes only  , when one products in  the cart then decrement button clicking time , if there is any other product then. there is no problem , no error is not getting***, Please take another look at the code( userhelpers.js)

Comment: I don't really understand everything you have going on in your Mongo query, but I would suggest at least checking for a `.length` on your `total` result from your query. Something like: `resolve(total.length > 0 ? total[0].total : 0)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is correct, Now not getting the error.Thanks for the support